# share session across multiple domains with the same app

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I have a cake app that runs two different domains, lets call them domain.com and otherdomain.com.  I want to share a single login and auth session between those two domains.  I've tried using database sessions and cake sessions, neither are able to save the session between the two domains. This is what I have in my core.php

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake',
    'checkAgent'=>false,
    'ini' => array(
        'session.cookie_secure' => false,
        'session.name'=>'mydomain',
        'session.cookie_domain'=>'mydomain',
    ),
    'cookie'=>'mydomain',
    'timeout'=>4320
));
```

Is ther anything else I am missing that would allow me to keep the session between the two domains?

Comment: Sessions are only valid for one domain, so you have to redirect to your otherdomain.com and login your user there. Then you can redirect back.

Comment: I managed to find a solution by making a curl request to the other domain and passing a key, then when the user visits the other domain i pass the same key and validate it. if it checks out, then they are automatically logged in.

Comment: @CowboyB Hello there! I'm doing something similar to this only that the other domain is from somebody else's and is just pointed to my site's ip address.. I want them to have the same session.. Is that possible in this setup?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. As long as the other domain is passing the session information to you.  You'll essentially have to log them in on your site if you get a key passed from the other site.  So, while they won't keep the same session, you can have it be transparent to the user that they are logged into two different sites.